# Upgrading to ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, asp.net-3.5, windows-server-2003

I have a server with some asp, asp.net 1.0 and 2.0 running on them. Now I'm planning to host 3.5 apps on them.

1. Do i have to make any changes to
   server other than installing
   framework to make it handle all my
   previous version apps?
2. Do i have to install new IIS or i can use same  iis for 3.5?
3. Do i have to install ajax newer version to suport ajax 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you don't need to change anything to your server. Just install the framework. Just make sure the application pools for your applications are running in the correct version of the framework.
2. You can't install a new version of IIS; It's tied to the version of the operating system (Server 2003 -> IIS6, Server 2008 -> IIS7)
3. Ajax is built in for 3.5. Again, you don't need to install anything

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2. You can use the same IIS
3.ASP.NET 3.5 comes with MS Ajax 3.5

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 2.0 and 3.5 can run side-by-side with no issues, since 3.5 isn't actually a rev to the 2.0 framework.

You would probably want to host your applications in different app pools, make sure that you specify the .NET version for the 1.0 app pool though!

With regard to AJAX, you may run into some assembly binding issues due to different versions of the 2.0 vs. 3.5 ajax assemblies. If that happens, make sure that you're explicitly stating in your web.config which version that app is using

Answer (score 2):

.Net 3.5 is simply addition of libraries to .net 2.0 so you should be safe running 3.5 and 2.0 webs on the same web server

If you output [System.Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) for 2.0 and 3.5 webs you can see that 2.0 is exececuting for both web behind the scenes